# How to calculate a^(1/n)?

Tags: java, floating-point, division, exponentiation

I am trying to calculate `a^(1/n)`, where `^` denotes exponentiation.

However, the following:

```
Math.pow(8, 1/3)
```

returns `1.0` instead of returning `2.0`.

Why is that?

Comment: Aww. Adorable. :)

Comment: While this question could use a better description, I don't really understand all of the downvotes.  This might be trivial to the majority of people here, but this sort of thing (integer division when float division is desired) is a very common issue, especially among new developers; this question will definitely help others.

Comment: @Saggio - Yep, it's a major stumbling block for beginners, and even some of us "experts" run afoul of it from time to time (and spend more time on the problem than we care to admit before we figure it out).

Comment: @Saggio Yea, we've all asked these sorts of questions at times. I don't understand the mass of down votes either.

Comment: It is a dupe, of course, but not a bad question.  Would be hard for a beginner to find the dupe.

Comment: You are right Saggio. Thank you so much. New developers will need like this supports.

Comment: I don't know why, but now days downvoting is becoming a fashion here... That downvoter could have earned about 120 reputation with 2-3 line answer now...
Useless downvoting on good questions should be restricted somehow...
This kind of downvoting is frustrating for beginners..

Comment: @SAM: I agree 100%. Part of the reason is that it's so much easier to downvote than to write a good answer (however brief)...

Comment: @SAM: There is nothing _wrong_ with downvoting. Upvoting means nothing without downvoting. The light means nothing without the dark. Life means nothing without serial killers... It's important not to take it personally.

Comment: @NPE Ignoring would be even easier ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Life means nothing without serial killers ?!?!?!?!?!

Comment: If 1/3 is not just an example but is something you use specifically, then you should consider `Math.cbrt` instead of `Math.pow`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that `1/3` uses [integer (truncating) division](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2), the result of which is zero. Change your code to

```
Math.pow(8, 1./3);
```

(The `.` turns the `1.` into a floating-point literal.)

Comment: Thank you so much. It seems trivial but important for me.

Comment: @GltknBtn: You're welcome. Everyone runs into this at some point. It's even less obvious when the division is part of a more complex expression, as is the case here.

Answer (score 5):

`1/3` becomes `0`(Because `1` and `3` are taken as `int` literals).

So you should make those literals float/double...

Do:

`Math.pow(8, 1f/3)`
or

`Math.pow(8, 1./3)`
or

`Math.pow(8, 1.0/3)`

Answer (score 4):

Try `Math.pow(8, (1.0f / 3.0f))` instead.

`1 / 3` will do an integer division, which will give you `8 ^ 0 = 1`

Comment: It's intuitively obvious to the rank neophyte!

Comment: @HotLicks: Were that so, this question would not exist.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - What question?

Comment: @HotLicks: The question taking up the page you're currently visiting in your internet web browser device.

Comment: By writing `1.0f / 3.0f` you are deliberately choosing the single-precision approximation of the mathematical value 1/3, instead of the double-precision approximation you could have had with `1.0 / 3.0`. I do not have a Java compiler but without being able to test it, I'd bet the difference is noticeable.